# Echarts get current time window

Tags: echarts, apache-echarts, ngx-echarts

I'm currently working on an Angular project where I have to display some data in a graph.
I'm using echarts for that through it's NGXecharts implementation.

My data comes from a backend app which scans a file system every 5 minutes and counts how many new files where added. So I have a scan status saved in db every 5 minutes with

`scan date : epoch timestamp,  number of new files : number`

We can easily imagine that after a year this makes a lot of records and data to be displayed. The graph gets very loaded with all these small samples.

My echart is a simple graph with xAxis type='time' an actual values on y.

What I want to do, but can't figure out how, is to catch the time window (start: date, end: date) whenever a user zooms (In/Out). With this and properly configured thresholds, I would be able to call my backend API to get more or less granularity in my dataset.

For Instance if the graph is very zoomed out showing several years, I would query my api asking for monthly aggregated data. If the window displays a full month, I would query daily aggregated data , etc.

I know that echarts has a dataZoom event that works but gives data values (the values of the y axis) and not the time values (min/max) of the x-axis.

```
{
    type: 'datazoom',
    // percentage of zoom start position, 0 - 100
    start: number
    // percentage of zoom finish position, 0 - 100
    end: number
    // data value of zoom start position; only exists in zoom event of triggered by toolbar
    startValue?: number
    // data value of zoom finish position; only exists in zoom event of triggered by toolbar
    endValue?: number
}
```

Is there any way to get the time window on a zoom event?
I know that some other librairies like Vis.js/Graph2D does this very well but it's lacking some other important features from echarts that I need.

Thanks a lot for you help.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same question a few days ago and solved my problem with the steps below:

1. You need to get the chart instance and also bind to `chartDataZoom` event

```html
<div
  echarts
  [options]="chartOption"
  (chartInit)="onChartInit($event)"
  (chartDataZoom)="onDataZoom()"
  class="demo-chart">
</div>
```

2. Create these two function and access dataZoom start and end values in option object.

```js
onChartInit(event: any): void {
  this.echartsInstance = event;
}

onDataZoom(): void {
  const dataZoom = this.echartsInstance.getOption().dataZoom[0];
  console.log(
    dataZoom.startValue, // You may need to format your output. Mine is a date as number.
    dataZoom.endValue
  );
  // Here you can filter your data and update your chart data.
}
```

One important thing is how dates are stored in options, they are converted to `number` type, so you need to convert back to `Date` and format to show as you expect.

Comment: Good to know! I'm glad to hep. @OlivierC, please mark my answer as the accepted answer :)

Comment: Thanks, sir.   Btw, you can type the event `onChartInit(event: ECharts)` and the `echartsInstance : ECharts` as well to have some IntelliSense.  Unfortunately, you still have to type the options too: `(this.echartsInstance.getOption() as EChartsOption) ` as the `getOption()` only returns `ECBasicOption` witch lacks many attributes, including  `dataZoom`.